# How to use bert layer for Multiple instance learning using TimeDistributed Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I want to perform Multiple Instance Learning Using Bert. A bag of instances contain 40 sentences. Each Sentence should output a label, and the final label should be average of all the labels.

I have tried using bert layer from tensorflow_hub. But I have no idea how to use it with TimeDistributed.

`bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",trainable=True)`

`pooled_output, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])`

Any suggestions/workarounds will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert, thus there are probably some issues to figure out, but it should give you a hint.
Except for the BERT encoder, you should use some preprocessing for your text:

```
bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4", trainable=True)  
# please keep in mind that the encoder is updated

sentence_input = keras.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
preprocessed = bert_preprocess(sentence_input)
encoded = bert_encoder(preprocessed)
outputs = encoded['pooled_output']  # this returns only single token for each sentence
bert_model = Model(inputs=sentence_input, outputs=outputs)

x = TimeDistributed(bert_model)(your_inputs)
```

and after the time distributed layer you should add an average pooling layer (please remember that the dimension of x depends on the BERT model size, it'd be (40,786) in your case I guess).